# Get all text content between tags from a URL?

Tags: java, html, dom, html-parsing, jsoup

By having a URL link. For example: http://www.engineersireland.ie/home.aspx

I can read them in by using java built in java.net.URL or Jsoup.

Then, I need to extract all text content between tags after  tag.

There will be tags within tags. What all I need is the text in the middle.

for example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <head id="head"><title>
        Engineers Ireland - Home
     </title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" /> 

    <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon"/> 
    <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon"/>
<body>
<div class="module-content">

        <p id="1">Members can login for access to exclusive content, event booking, shop discounts and more...</p>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Login Details</legend>
                <div class="formline">
                    <label for="1" id="1">Your Membership Number</label>
                    <input name="1" type="text" id="1" title="Your Membership Number" class="login-username clearlabel" />
                    <span id="1e" class="ErrorLabel" style="display:none;">Enter your membership number</span>
                </div>
                <div class="formline">
                    <label for="1" id="adasdasd">Password</label>
                    <input name="asdasd" type="password" id="dfbsdf" title="Password" class="login-password clearlabel" />
                    <span id="drthd" class="ErrorLabel" style="display:none;">Enter your password</span>
                </div>
                <div class="formline">
                    <input name="aseresrr" type="checkbox" id="bstg" class="login-remember" />
                    <label for="ryjmf" id="asrats" class="remember">Remember Me</label>

                    <div class="button grey">
                        <input type="submit" name="fgn" value="LOGIN" onclick="sdf;, false, false))" id="sdfsdf" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        <ul class="arrow">
            <li><a href="/site/reset-password.aspx">Forgot your password?</a></li>
            <li><a href="/membership/apply.aspx">Haven't registered yet?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

From this html code, all I need are just:

```
Your Membership Number
Enter your membership number
Password
Enter your password
Remember Me
```

Other thing is that,

```
Keep in mind, the tag names and the number of tag are always random depend on the web page iteself.
```

Any help? By using Jsoup or java? Thx

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked at the JSoup documentation? What rules are there for what text you want and what text you don't? It looks like the text content of all `<label/>` and `<span/>` elements within the `<fieldset/>`, and nothing else? Are those actually the requirements? Why, for example, is the text from the `<p/>` tag or the links at the bottom excluded?

Comment: Yeah. I looked up the Jsoup's docs. Studying it now. For the example above, it's just a random one. I need all the text between any tags after <body>. The tags may contain tags, but I need the text in the very middle of all these tag layers. Thx

Comment: If you're still researching, just scroll down.  I've posted a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following, you can specify which section of the document you want to extract text from by passing in the correct CSS query to the getStringsFromUrl method.  To search the whole document pass in null.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.StringUtil;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JSoupTest {
    /*
     Outputs:
        Members can login for access to exclusive content, event booking, shop discounts and more...
        Your Login Details
        Your Membership Number
        Enter your membership number
        Password
        Enter your password
        Remember Me
        Forgot your password?
        Haven't registered yet?
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://localhost/test.html";
        List<String> strings = getStringsFromUrl(url, null);
        for(String string : strings) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getStringsFromUrl(String url, String cssQuery) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements elements = StringUtil.isBlank(cssQuery)
                ? document.getElementsByTag("body")
                : document.select(cssQuery);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        elements.traverse(new TextNodeExtractor(strings));
        return strings;
    }

    private static class TextNodeExtractor implements NodeVisitor {
        private final List<String> strings;

        public TextNodeExtractor(List<String> strings) {
            this.strings = strings;
        }

        @Override
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                TextNode textNode = ((TextNode) node);
                String text = textNode.getWholeText();
                if (!StringUtil.isBlank(text)) {
                    strings.add(text);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. In this case, it did work with the example I gave. But in real cases, we don't know how many tags that in the <body> and we don't know how many layers of tags surrounded the text. But all I need is the text and the program just accept a simple URL. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineer will be the input in Jsoup.connect(""); Then, all the text that required will be returned.

Comment: Well your question stated that you only wanted a subset of the actual strings from the document.  If you want all of the strings, just replace the document.select() call with document.body() and it will return everything

Comment: Edited to more precisely demonstrate what you were looking for.  Notice that it returns more strings than what you had originally declared in the topic question.

Comment: It seems working. I will study your code and made midifications to adapt my program. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

Use HtmlUnit Libraries in java so that you can find tag content of your choice.

Please visit Below link :

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: The tag name is random. All I need is the text between tags. No matter how many tags layers outside a text.

Comment: are you using HTML tag or any other tags?please let me now.

Comment: if you want to parse only html then HTMLUnit will definitely help you. I have used few days before.

Comment: Don't post link only answers. Links tent to break which will make your answer invalid. Instead create simple solution based on article from link and leave link as source of more informations. More info at: [are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: "...and post as answer" I just hope you meant "...and post *in* this answer" since there is no reason to create new post when you can simply [[edit]] this one :)

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis Thx for your comments. I'm using html tags. The program accepts a URL as an input to retrieve the text between tags within <body>.